# Issues with 2 cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have issues with 2 cookies, that I cannot remove via PHP or Javascript.

1) _ga GA1.2.1247399448.1424678072 .mydomainname.com

2) an _utmz with this value:

```
44433727.1430294622.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions
/431672/how-to-translate-strings-in-js
```

and like domain .jquery.com

I need to clean all cookies with a click, 'cause the EU cookie law.

Please, could you help me to remove them?

For the first one, I DON'T call no analytics code, until the accept from the user (but I cannot remove it).

For the second one, I don't understand why and because I have it...

Comment: Those seem to be Google Analytics related cookies... Are you sure you never used it in the past ?

Comment: Yes, I used it in this domain. But i cleared all cookies, but I don't know how clear cookies with dot in name. And for the second one is from domain .jquery.com

Comment: Can you post the different ways you've tried to delete all cookies ?

Comment: 1) document.cookie = "_ga=;domain=\"./mydomain.com\";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";  and 2 using a javascript plugin: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie ( in this case: Cookies.set('_ga', '', { domain: '.mydomain.com', expires:-365 });

Comment: Is that line break intentional?

Comment: You know, this isn't limited to JavaScript. You can post it under every language at the same time!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have setup a custom server using [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) and the cookie is being removed correctly using js-cookie [v2.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.1) in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="js-cookie.js"></script>
<script>
    Cookies.defaults.path = "";
    document.cookie = "_utmz=44433727.1430294622.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions" +
        "/431672/how-to-translate-strings-in-js";
    alert( Cookies.get( "_utmz" ) );
    Cookies.remove( "_utmz" );
    alert( Cookies.get( "_utmz" ) );
</script>
```

It gets an alert with the cookie value first and then an alert `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one i.e Google analytics cookies You can do add the following code on your headers.php : -

```
<script>
if(document.cookie.split('; ').findIndex(x => x.split('=')[0] == 'cookiename') >= 0) 
{

}else{
    window["ga-disable-UA-7358061-1"] = true;
}
</script>
```

window["ga-disable-UA-7358061-1"] = true; this will disable your google analytics cookies